# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am insert data in db is good. The problem is after inserted data i am trying to get last inserted data primary key column. But i can't how to solve this problem.

note : i am using jpql , Thanks

```
public void insertData(String hcpHceId) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

            em.getTransaction().begin();
//          Query query = em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO mdm_id (hcp_hce_id)  VALUES(:id)" );
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO mdm_id (hcp_hce_id)  VALUES(?)");
            query.setParameter(1, hcpHceId);
            query.executeUpdate(); // Successfully inserted data
            List list = query.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();  // Error line
            em.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(error.getMessage());
        } finally {
            em.close();;
        }


}
```

Comment: how do you expect to get result while your query is still an update statement?

Comment: i can't understood what you tell

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve the list from the same execute query. Query is an immutable object. You must create a new query with the proper select statement, so you will be able to retrieve data from database.

After the executeUpdate, create the new query using, v.g. (as you did not show your entity graph, using native sql):

```
Query retQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT hcp_hce_id FROM mdm_id LIMIT 1");
String id = (String) retQuery.getSingleResult();
assert(id == hcpHceId);
```